# Dripping pipe in crawlspace - how much of an emergency?

Tags: plumbing, leak, valve, mold, crawlspace

I disconnected a refrigerator supply line (to the ice maker). The original tube was made of copper and I plan to replace it with braided stainless steel. However, I'm having some painting done this week, so I'd like to wait a few days before hooking it back up.

My problem: The shutoff valve for the supply line doesn't completely work, so there's a slow drip (every 5-10 seconds) from the disconnected valve. The dripping shutoff valve is in the crawl space, which has a few ground-level vents and a moisture barrier on the floor (covered by gravel).

Will the amount of water from a slow drip cause any damage (e.g. mold) if it's only left dripping for a few days?

EDIT: I will be collecting the water with a bucket and dumping it daily.

Comment: Put a bucket under it, and dump it outside.  Reduce the moisture from staying around.

Comment: [This calculator](https://water.usgs.gov/edu/activity-drip.html) says that 6 drips/minute (one drip every 6 seconds) will yield 1 US gallon/day of water. Perhaps you can place a several-gallon tub under the dripping valve, and thereafter remove the dripped water from under the house when the painting is complete and the plumbing repaired.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I put a bucket underneath, which I plan to empty at least daily. (I can't tell yet if it will overflow, but based on the calcuation above, it probably won't.) I've edited the original post to add that detail.

Comment: This is opinion, so not posted as an Answer. I think emptying the bucket daily for several days will have no or an insignificant effect on humidity down there. I'd go right ahead in this fashion.

Comment: With the new info, it should not cause problems.  Problems arise when a drip soaks into something and there is moisture/dampness staying for a long time.  Using a bucket gets rid of any soaking, so any increase in moisture in the air should be taken care of by ventilation.

Comment: You can always install a cap/plug on the open end of the pipe.

Comment: That's what we ended up doing, but even with some plumber's tape, there's still a very slight leak. It's under control now, though—a few drops per day. Now it can wait until we have a plumber out for something else. Thanks, everyone!